# Dial digits (1 or 2) when call active/answered from custom Default Dialer in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-dialer

Im making a **Default Dialer App** in Android replacing built-in phone dialer. Everything is working fine, call is attending as well as rejecting.

But when the call attends: When suppose operator asks to press  **"1"**  for this and **"2"** for this. 
 How can I send these **(1 or 2)** commands to operator programmatically without interrupting my custom calling screen and without going out of my custom call screen. 
Things I have tried for pressing button 3: 
   **Intent intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel://3"))

startActivity(intent)** 
 But the above code prompt me a dialog **"Unable to make conference call."**
Thank you.

Comment: That's called a DTMF tone.  Sending them over a call is not supported in Android.  You can try playing it over the speakers and hope its loud enough (and still the right frequency after going over the speaker and a mic) to see if it works, but that's the best you can do.

Comment: Thank you for your response @GabeSechan but i have solved it. As Im making my own custom default dialer app and using InCallService, so there I have I found a function named playDtmfTone(digit: char) which have solved my problem.